# scope value changed but watch did not fire

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use a directive for geolocation input and gives you back the coordinates value in a scope. I want to watch when the scope gets the value so I could do something.

[my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fr8hl9ilTeCphY3mNlRy?p=preview)

```
    angular.module('app', ['ngAutocomplete'])
    .directive('myForm', function() {

         return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'myForm.html',

        };

    }) 
    .controller('formCtrl', function ($scope)
    {
          //watch for details change
         $scope.$watch($scope.details, function () {

            //alert('details changed')
            $scope.formItem.longitude = $scope.details.geometry.location.lng();
            $scope.formItem.latitude = $scope.details.geometry.location.lat();

        }, true);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this,

```
$scope.$watch('details', function () {
    //alert('details changed')
    $scope.formItem.longitude = $scope.details.geometry.location.lng();
    $scope.formItem.latitude = $scope.details.geometry.location.lat();
}, true);
```

Comment: thanks alot! are there any better approach to $watch?